# SQLiteException with android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
String insertQuery= "INSERT INTO"+ Table_Name +"(Coloum1, Coloum2, Coloum3, Coloum4,Coloum5,Coloum6,Coloum7,Coloum8,Coloum9) VALUES('fname','lname','dob','address','pin','city','tel','eid','date')" ;       
sd.execSQL(insertQuery);
```

I want to write in sqlite db throu  this code but it throws an exception:

```
08-24 09:51:53.858: E/(595): Exception   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTORegistrationTable11": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTORegistrationTable11(Coloum1, Coloum2, Coloum3, Coloum4,Coloum5,Coloum6,Coloum7,Coloum8,Coloum9) VALUES('fname','lname','dob','address','pin','city','tel','eid','date')
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the SQL it's complaining about "INTORegistrationTable11"

See the lack of a space?

This:

```
String insertQuery= "INSERT INTO" + Table_Name + "(Coloum1, ...
```

should be:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO " + Table_Name + " (Coloum1, ...
```

Reading error messages carefully is an important part of software engineering.

Answer (score 0):

```
String insertQuery= "INSERT INTO "+ Table_Name +" (Coloum1, Coloum2, Coloum3, Coloum4,Coloum5,Coloum6,Coloum7,Coloum8,Coloum9) VALUES('fname','lname','dob','address','pin','city','tel','eid','date')" ;
```

Add a space after INTO.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces, be very careful when composing such strings for SQL, always make sure there is proper space before and after each SQL symbol and word. Also, why not use the built in `insert()` function and provide your data through `ContentValues` ?